# Knockout js en Magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento2, knockoutjs

Buen día comunidad.

Quería pedir apoyo, ya que estoy modificando un comparador en Magento, veo que en la sección cuenta con knockout y jala los atributos por medio de "data-bind", el código es el siguiente:

```
<figure class="bar-sticky__fig js-changeView">
  <img src='' data-bind="attr: {'src' : image_src}" alt="" style="max-width: 70px;display: block;margin-right: 10px;" class="image__compare">
  <figcaption class="bar-sticky__caption product-item-name" style="text-transform: inherit;">
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: name" class="product-item-link compare__txt-terminal"></a>
    <a data-bind="html: final-price" class="product-item-link"></a>
    <span class="bar-sticky__txt"></span>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-post': remove_url}" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove This Item') ?>" class="i-x bar-sticky__btn js-stickyBtn action delete" style="position: relative;color: #313235;text-decoration: none !important;left: -5px;top: -25px;border: 1px solid #F5F5F5; background-color: #F5F5F5; border-radius: 50%">
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove This Item') ?></span>
  </a>
</figure>
```

Quiero agregar el precio pero no encuentro el nombre del atributo, de qué manera puedo encontrar el arreglo en donde se encuentran definidos esos atributos **product_url**, **name**, **image_src**, etc.

Muchas gracias de antemano por el apoyo.